# Prove there exists $M<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|\le M|x| $ holding for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Suppose $f(x)$ be bounded and differentiable over $\mathbb R$, and
> $|f'(x)|<1$ for any $x$. Prove there exists $M<1$ such that
> $|f(x)-f(0)|\le M|x|$ holding for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Probably, we may consider applying MVT, say $$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right|=|f'(\xi)|<1,$$ but which can only imply $M\le 1$, not $M<1$ we wanted. How to improve the inequality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, defined as
$$
 g(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} & \text{ if } x \ne 0  \\
f'(0) & \text{ if } x = 0  
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous, with $\lim_{x \to - \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to + \infty} g(x)= 0$.

It follows that $|g|$ attains its maximum at some point $x_0$, so that
$$
 |g(x)| \le |g(x_0)| = \left|\frac{f(x_0)-f(0)}{x_0-0}\right| = |f'(\xi_0)| =: M < 1
$$
for some fixed $\xi_0$, and all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 6):

You can assume without loss of generality that $f(0) = 0$.

Suppose to the contrary that no such $M$ exists. Then for each $k \ge 2$ there exists a point $x_k$ satisfying $$|f(x_k)| > \left( 1 - \frac 1k \right) |x_k|.$$
Since $f$ is bounded there is a constant $C$ with $|f(x_k)| \le C$ for all $k$, implying that $|x_k| \le \dfrac{kC}{k-1} \le 2C$ for all $k$. Thus $\{x_k\}$ is bounded and has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_j}\}$. Denote the limit of this subsequence by $x$.  Since $f(x_{k_j}) \to f(x)$ and $$|f(x_{k_j})| > \left( 1 - \frac 1{k_j} \right) |x_{k_j}|$$  you may let $j \to \infty$ to discover that $|f(x)| \ge |x|$. According to the mean-value theorem there must be a point $\xi$ in between $0$ and $x$ with $|f'(\xi)| \ge 1$, contrary to hypothesis.

Comment: good. so then, unbounded $f$  would allow $x -  \arctan x$

Comment: Nice proof. I should think of this proof whenever I tell my students "to prove an existence theorem, you have to construct the object whose existence is being asserted", and then remember to add "OR you can apply earlier existence statements".

Comment: But what if $x=0$?